# Bind a row of a grid to switch between a gridview and text

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, winrt-xaml

so on the mainpage of my app, I have a grid with two rows.
First row is title etc.
Second row is a gridview of a bunch of data.

I would like to bind the second row of my main grid to a boolean or something, that checks if a user is logged in.

If the user is not logged in, the second row will only display text: "Please Log In"

If the user is logged in, then the gridview with the data will populate.

As it is right now, my code just has a collectionviewsource with the data

```
<CollectionViewSource
x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
Source="{Binding data}"
IsSourceGrouped="true"
ItemsPath="information"
d:Source="{Binding data, Source={d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=local:HomeDesignData}}"/>
```

then the grid with two rows, and the gridview in the first row

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard500x130ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
```

so again, I just want to find a way to switch out the gridview entirely for simple text, bound to a boolean or something that checks if the user is logged in

Thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy way to accomplish this is to overlay a grid on the GridView and only show if it the user is not logged in. You would take advantage of a BooleanToVisibilityValueConverter for this.

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        Grid.Row="2"
        ...
    />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Black"
          Visibility="{Binding IsLoggedIn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"> <!-- The Grid control will fill the entire row
        <TextBlock Text="Log in dummy!" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution-- I do have a bool to visibility converter already, but I'm not sure how to call it.  Could you help me out?

 public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
 {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
   return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
   return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
  }
 }

Comment: You need to add the converter to the resources of an element. See updated answer which includes the converter in the Grid Resources